# How to delete item from ListView and ViewModel ObservableRangeCollection in Xamrin.Form?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I want to delete item from ListView and ViewModel ObservableRangeCollection in Xamrin.Form.

EmployeeResultsPage

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeResultsListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeResults}"
          RowHeight="200"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshDataCommand}"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshingData, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemAppearing="Employee_ItemAppearing"
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:EmployeeResultViewCell />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

EmployeeResultViewModel

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class EmployeeResultsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private async Task LoadEmployee()
    {
        EmployeeResults = GetDataUsingAPI(); //15 records per call
        OnDeleteEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(async (model) => await DeleteEmployee(model));
    }

    public ObservableRangeCollection<ExtendedEmployee> EmployeeResults { get; set; }

    public string EmployeePhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public ICommand OnDeleteMessageCommand { get; set; }
    private async Task DeleteEmployee(object obj)
    {
        //get object here
    }
}
```

EmployeeResultViewCell

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem
        Text="Delete"
        IsDestructive="true"
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDeleteEmployeeCommand, Source={x:Reference EmployeeResultsPage}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
<ViewCell.View>
    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150">
        <Image x:Name="EmployeeImage" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150"
        Source="{Binding EmployeePhotoUrl}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding EmployeeName}" FontSize="18" TextColor="Grey"/>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell.View>
```

CS File

```
public partial class EmployeeResultViewCell : CustomViewCell
{
    public EmployeeResultViewCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        var employee = (BindingContext as ExtendedEmployee);
    }

}
```

Changed: Remove click event and add binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MVVM you are not using events, but rather commands in your viewmodels that you can bind to commands of your views. The most MVVM way to achieve what you want would be to add a `ICommand` bindable property to your cell

```
public partial class EmployeeResultViewCell : CustomViewCell
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   The <see cref="DeleteCommand" /> bindable property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty DeleteCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SealCheckListPage.DeleteCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(SealCheckListPage), default(ICommand));

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the DeleteCommand that is called when we'd like to delete an employee.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)this.GetValue(SealCheckListPage.DeleteCommandProperty);

        set => this.SetValue(SealCheckListPage.DeleteCommandProperty, value);
    }

    private void MenuItemDelete_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteCommand?.Execute(BindingContext);
    }
}
```

Now you can bind the `DeleteCommand` to your viewmodel

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:EmployeeResultViewCell DeleteCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference Page}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Please note that the page that contains the `ListView` must have `x:Name="Page"` in order to bind the command correctly. Admittedly, binding the command that way is not really optimal, but as far as I know this is the best we can do, MVVM-wise.

The last thing you'll have to do is to add an `ICommand` property to your viewmodel

```
public class EmployeeResultsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private async Task LoadEmployee()
    {
        EmployeeResults = GetDataUsingAPI(); //15 records per call

        DeleteCommand = new Command<ExtendedEmployee>(OnDelete);
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }

    private void OnDelete(ExtendedEmployee employee)
    {
        // delete the employee from the collection
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Now, when your cell receives the event, it executes the command, which is bound to the command in your viewmodel. When this command is executed, it executes the passed delegate `OnDelete` in which you have access to the collection you'd like to delete the `ExtendedEmployee` from.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you very much. I have edited my question and set command in my MenuItem. But I am still not able to call Command of ViewModel of ListPage. Can you please correct me. I think there is something wrong in this line of MenuItem `Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDeleteEmployeeCommand, Source={x:Reference EmployeeResultsPage}}"`

Comment: @NanjiMange Have you checked the debug output? If binding failed, there should be a debug message telling you *what* failed. Furthermore check if `MenuItemDelete_Clicked` by setting a breakpoint there. Have you created the property *and* the `BindableProperty` for `DeleteCommand` (or simply `Command`, as you like it).

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you very much. You saved my day.